# Build - frontend stage is skipped in Pipeline

Tags: s4sdk

I am trying to execute the front-end stage in pipeline. But it is skipped in the pipeline. I added below code in `pipeline_config.yml` file.

```
executeNpm:
  dockerImage: 's4sdk/docker-node-chromium'
```

Can someone please help?

Thanks,
Sankeerth

Comment: Does your project have a `package.json` file? The front-end build is skipped, if the project does not have that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be that your project does not have a `package.json` file. The whole front-end part (build and test) of the pipeline is skipped, if this is not the case. If you have created your project using one of your Maven archetypes (which is the recommended way), you're probably missing `package.json` and the frontend application itself. An example for an application which includes a frontend is the [CostCenter Controller](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-examples/tree/master/Costcenter-Controller-CF) in our example projects. The frontend application is under the path `application/src/main/resources/static` in that project.

Side note: It should not be necessary to configure the Docker image used for running the front-end tests, unless you have special requirements which are not met by our default image.

Hope this helps,
Florian

Comment: Did this answer resolve your problem? If not, can you go more into detail of what you would expect and what happens? If yes, marking the answer as "accepted" was highly appreciated. Best, Florian